# Prevent default error message with firebase-ui

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using firebase-ui and Google Identity Platform for login.  I'm using a Google cloud function to limit the email addresses that can be used to login.  It is mostly working except that I can't prevent the default ugly error message:
[image]

I'd like to precent this from appearing and instead use my own error message.

I have a callback function that looks like this:

```
  'signInFailure': function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    //return Promise.resolve();
    //return false;
    //return true;
  }
```

You can see in the comments the variants I've tried.

How do I prevent this error message from being shown?

=== UPDATE ===

Turns out that `signInFailure` is not being called.  There is some other exception handling that causes this error message to be shown.  Would be great to have a workaround, but I suspect that I just can't use firebase-ui.  :(

Comment: How does your cloud function get hooked in to the process?

Comment: @Phil, I created a Google Identity Platform beforeCreate trigger here: https://console.cloud.google.com/customer-identity/settings  The trigger is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for Google Identity Platform blocking functions](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions) states

> Note: Blocking functions are only available for use with Identity Platform. They are not supported with Firebase Authentication.

I don't understand what this means exactly since there is so much crossover between Identity Platform (IP) and Firebase Auth (the IP documentation frequently refers to Firebase but is that IP or Firebase? Who knows?), but it seems at least that these blocking functions don't work with Firebase UI.

A workaround is to do the same exact processing of cloud function after the fact on your own server and, if necessary, delete the just created user.

I actually like this solution better because I'd rather not maintain the cloud function.